# Are the following 2 lines the same in Java?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

```
return (ConcurrentHashMap)sortedMap;
```

and

```
return new ConcurrentHashMap(sortedMap);
```

Comment: No. (what else to add here?)

Comment: Will this even compile? What is sortedMap?

Comment: @qqilihq I'm pretty sure the purpose of the question is to why they're different.

Comment: The first one transforms sortedMap into a ConcurrentHashMap if it isn't one alredy. The second one creates a new one using sortedMap as a reference.

Answer (score 7):

No. The first one is casting `sortedMap` into `ConcurrentHashMap`. The second one is creating a new `ConcurrentHashMap` instance using the provided `sortedMap`; it will have the same mappings as `sortedMap`.

In the first one you will have one object that has just been casted into a new type, whereas in the second one two have two objects; one is the original `sortedMap`, and the other is a new instance of `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't.

The first casts sortedMap to a `ConcurrentHashMap`. Casting doesn't create a new object.

The second statement creates a new object with the same mappings as sortedMap.